# `fs.lstat` raises no error after I manually delete a file, but reading the file does

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, filesystems

I want to submit to you this question:

If I delete a file manually (that is, not using `fs.unlink` in Node but using the GUI or a CLI command) after the server has already started, Node says that the file still exists when I use `fs.lstat` but if I try to read this file, Node throws `ENOENT` because the file does not exist.

I thought maybe the cause is that Node has an internal file list created when the server starts, and only when Node's filesystem functions are used to manipulates files and directories would this list be updated. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I'm sorry for the grammar mistakes, I'm italian ahhahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the bug!

At the server start, I create a folder.

When after the server start, I deleted this folder for a test (is a cache folder), I didn't remember that the file requested was in this folder and Node normally says "not found stupid"... ahahah sorry guys and thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

When you call `fs.lstat` node is going to request the information from the operating system. It is not going to fetch it from some internal cache.

This being said, it is quite possible to write a Node application that won't behave properly if files disappear after it is initialized. But this is not a fault in Node but a fault in the application itself.